# Hibernate generates select after update

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue with Hibernate in spring-boot.

So, mapping in spring-boot is like this:

Class A

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private C c;     
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<B> b;
```

Class B

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private A a;
```

Now when I do update (`repositoryA.save(a)`) of object of class A via JpaRepository<A, Integer> with value of `b=null`, hibernate generates this queries:

```sql
    update a
    select b from B where aId = ?
```

So why is this second select query needed? I tried to remove `CascadeType.PERSIST` but the result is same.

I don't what this, because the list can have many objects and it can affect the performance.

**UPDATE:**

Controller:

```java
    @PutMapping("/edit")
    public A editA(@Valid @RequestBody A a, @RequestParam String idC){
           return serviceA.editA(a, idC);
    }
```

Service:

```java
    @Transactional
    public A editA(A a, String idC){
          C c = serviceC.getById(idC);
          a.setC(c); 
         return repositoryA.save(a);
    }
```

Comment: please share your controller and service layer codes.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that save method either updates or creates a record depending on whether it already exists or not. If you don't want to the select afterwards, maybe try just a plain "update"?

Comment: I work with JpaRepository, there is no plain update method. But I'm making sure that there is already object with the ID which I'm giving as parameter, so it does updates the record and after that the SELECT statement is fired.
Is it possible that this is problem with Jackson?

Comment: Ok, now I understand more what you're facing. The way Hibernate works is that entities you work on should remain in the session, that means, that whenever an operation is performed on an entity, it should be updated to ensure consistency. If that select causes you some performance problems, consider using a query instead of triggering a CrudRepository's save operation.